# Use VB.Net & networkstream to publish text string to web browser

Tags: xml, vb.net, browser, networkstream

I have searched without success for a method of publishing a text string to a socket for viewing by a web browser and other devices.  I have implemented VB.Net code that already generates the desired string output to a log file for debugging.  The program will push initial values for set variables to the client upon connection and then scan for updates to the variables on a set interval.  Any updates will be pushed out as a new string in this manner:

timestamp|dataid1|dataitem1|dataid2|dataitem2|dataid3|dataitem3|dataid4|dataitem4|etc

The updates might look like this if only 2 and 4 were changed:

timestamp|dataid2|dataitem2|dataid4|dataitem4

I believe I need to use networkstream and TCPListener to detect a client's request and initialize my communication.  I have found a couple of example online with no luck implementing them.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This question is really too broad to be answered but if you want to implement a TCP client server communication have a look at this: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Simple-Multi-User-TCPIP-43cc3b44

You may want to [have a look into WCF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33995/Getting-Started-with-WCF) though as this may be a better framework to work with in your circumstance

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I have taken a loop at both of the links you provided.  I suppose I should mention that I am very new to Visual Basic and .Net in general.  I think part of the difficulty I've had with a lot of the online examples is they seem to set up server and client which communicate bidirectionally.  In my case I only need to publish a updating text string to a port for viewing by a pre-existing client.  If I have already assembled my data into a string, what is the most straightforward method for publishing this to a network stream? @Matt